# How can I transfer a serialize array to a database in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I transfer a serialize array to a database in PDO ?

*My databases:*

```
id | name | surname
```

*My function which does not work:*

```
public function save($value2, $value3)
{
        $array = array('id' => '', ‘name’ => "$value2", ‘surname’ => "$value3");
        $serialize = serialize($array);

        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(NULL, 'serialize', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($serialize)."')") or die(mysqli_error());

}
```

For information, my $value1 is null because I use the auto-increment in my table.

Comment: you tagged as pdo yet you're using a `mysqli_` function; you can't mix those. Unless you're asking to convert that to PDO for you.

Comment: you also have curly quotes here `‘ ‘` and is already breaking your code.

Comment: *"How can I transfer a serialize array to a database in PDO ?"* - Start with the manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and I for one will not convert that for you, nor should anyone else. Try and learn is the best way to do just that; "learn". Good luck.

Comment: and you learned absolutely nothing today, except opened your mouth while someone threw you a fish. That comment of yours [*"(Unlike some on this site)"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962909/how-can-i-transfer-a-serialize-array-to-a-database-in-pdo#comment73021668_42963193) - really; you could have kept that to yourself. I gave you a link to consult but you decided not to do anything about it. Your question showed no effort. We help those who help themselves.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you’re supposed to be using PDO, you should finish the job that way. While you’re there use **pepared** statements which will handle all of the tricky parts, such as strings which break SQL.

Assuming that you already have a PDO object `$pdo`, this gives you:

```
$prepared=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(NULL,?,?)');
$prepared->execute(array('serialize',$serialize));
```

You can also use prepared statements if you’re using `mysqli_` statements.

Comment: Thank you for your sympathy (Unlike some on this site) ! This is exactly what I was looking for ! :)